# How can I fix that my divs are overlapping?

Tags: html, css

I know that this question has been asked a lot but the solutions for other posts don't work for me. On my front-page I have a section that works like a tab section, having 4 buttons on the bottom of this section that if clicked will load different content into this section. That all works fine but when I resize my browser, the row with my buttons overlaps with the content above it in that section. Adding display block is not solving the issue. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Here is the HTML and CSS code:

```
<div class="container2">

  <div id="hp_slider_1" class="tabcontent">

    <div class="left">
      <div class="tabheading">
        <p>Heading</p>
      </div>

      <div class="slidertab">
        <?php echo do_shortcode('[smartslider3 slider=14]');?>
      </div>


    </div>


    <div class="right">
      <div class="tabheading">
        <p>Heading</p>
      </div>

      <div class="texttab">
        <h4 class="rightheading">Content1</h4>
        <p class="righttext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <a href="#" class="button_learnmore">Learn more.</a>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="hp_slider_2" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Paris</h3>
    <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="hp_slider_3" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Tokyo</h3>
    <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="hp_slider_4" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>fourth</h3>
    <p>Hello.</p>
  </div>





  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'hp_slider_1')">Button1 </button>

    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'hp_slider_2')">Button2</button>

    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'hp_slider_3')">Button3</button>

    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event,'hp_slider_4')">Button4</button>
  </div>



</div>
```

CSS

```
/* Container2 Styling */

.container2 {
  overflow:hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #81A1AA;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow: auto;

}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.tabheading {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.left {
float: left;
width: 50%;
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
}


.slidertab {
padding-top: 50px;
display: block;

}

.right {
float: right;
width: 50%;
height: 100vh;
}

.texttab {
position: relative;

padding: 30px 70px;
}

.rightheading {

}

.righttext {
padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.button_learnmore {
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #4A6971;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #4A6971 5%, #81A1AA 100%);
    background-color:#4A6971;
    border-radius:8px;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:12px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.button_learnmore:hover {
    background: #B5CFD6;
  color: black;

}

.button_learnmore:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}


/* Style the tab */
.tab {

  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: black solid 1px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;

}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px 50px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;

}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  color: #4A6971;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  color: #4A6971;
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest maybe moving the buttons out of the container div.

Comment: But I want the buttons to be included in the 100vh, so that the buttons and the content above make up 100% of the screen together

Comment: You can use flex box, but you'll want your structure to look closer to this I think
.container2 // flex
   .container-for-tabs
   .tab

Comment: I tried using Flexbox but the button row was still overlapping with the right and left div when I resized the browser

Comment: Your intended goal is to have, if I understand it correctly, the top area for content scrollable while the bottom tab bar is fixed at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: No, my hp is section in 3 divs. Each div should always fill up 100% of the screen, even if the browser size is changed. This tab from my code is in the second container div. In this container div are basically 3 main divs. The right and the left div (each taking up 50% width) and the button row that should be below the right and left div, having 100% width. The issue is, when I now reduce the height of my browser, the button row/div is overlapping with my right and left div. But I want the button div to basically push the right and left div, so that it is not overlapping

Answer (score 1):

Seeing your code and guessing the future expansion of the application I believe you have to use **flex** to solve the issue.

```
.tab{
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
border:black solid 1px;
black solid 1px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-content: center;
justify-content: center;
}
```

So your code will look as shown below.

```css
   .container2 {
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #81A1AA;
        color: white;
        position: relative;
        font-size: 16px;
        overflow: auto;

    }

    /* Style the tab content */
    .tabcontent {
        text-align: center;
        display: none;
    }

    .tabheading {
        font-size: 16px;
        padding: 10px 0;
    }

    .left {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
    }


    .slidertab {
        padding-top: 50px;
        display: block;

    }

    .right {
        float: right;
        width: 50%;
        height: 100vh;
    }

    .texttab {
        position: relative;

        padding: 30px 70px;
    }

    .rightheading {}

    .righttext {
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }

    .button_learnmore {
        box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #4A6971;
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4A6971 5%, #81A1AA 100%);
        background-color: #4A6971;
        border-radius: 8px;
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .button_learnmore:hover {
        background: #B5CFD6;
        color: black;

    }

    .button_learnmore:active {
        position: relative;
        top: 1px;
    }


    /* Style the tab */
    .tab {

        
        border: black solid 1px;
       text-align: center;
width: 100%;


position: absolute;
bottom: 0;

display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-content: center;
justify-content: center;

    }

    /* Style the buttons inside the tab */
    .tab button {
        background-color: inherit;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 15px 50px;
        transition: 0.3s;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;

    }

    /* Change background color of buttons on hover */
    .tab button:hover {
        color: #4A6971;
    }

    /* Create an active/current tablink class */
    .tab button.active {
        color: #4A6971;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container2">

        <div id="hp_slider_1" class="tabcontent">

            <div class="left">
                <div class="tabheading">
                    <p>Heading</p>
                </div>

                <div class="slidertab">
                    <?php echo do_shortcode('[smartslider3 slider=14]');?>
                </div>


            </div>


            <div class="right">
                <div class="tabheading">
                    <p>Heading</p>
                </div>

                <div class="texttab">
                    <h4 class="rightheading">Content1</h4>
                    <p class="righttext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                        incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                        ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
                        in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
                        cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="button_learnmore">Learn more.</a>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="hp_slider_2" class="tabcontent">
            <h3>Paris</h3>
            <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="hp_slider_3" class="tabcontent">
            <h3>Tokyo</h3>
            <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="hp_slider_4" class="tabcontent">
            <h3>fourth</h3>
            <p>Hello.</p>
        </div>





        <div class="tab">
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'hp_slider_1')">Button1 </button>

            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'hp_slider_2')">Button2</button>

            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'hp_slider_3')">Button3</button>

            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event,'hp_slider_4')">Button4</button>
        </div>



    </div>
```

Comment: Was it the answer you were looking for ??

Comment: I tried this but the bottom div with the buttons is still overlapping with the above divs when I resize the browser. Thank you anyway!

Comment: I didn't understand the problem, can you please explain. Can you try adding some margin to your buttons inside the .tab to see if that's what you are talking about.

Comment: I don't think this is a margin issue. Basically, in a section div, I have 3 main divs. A right div, a left div (each of them taking up 50% width) and a 3rd div below these two divs that includes the buttons and has a width of 100%. I want that all of these three divs make up 100% of the screen, even if you resize it. That is currently fine. But when I reduce the screen height by resizing the browser, then the button div (the one at the bottom with 100% width) is overlapping with the right and left div. But I want the Button div to not overall with the other divs. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think I got your problem. You have hidden the container2 so I did understand the overlapping till now. Just give me couple of mintues I will post the answer

Comment: I recommend to completely re-write the CSS part with the grid. Fixing what you have could create problems in the future. If you do with the grid it's so simple and you can easily expand it in the future.

Comment: I don't think my container2 is hidden? And how would I solve this with grid?

Comment: Do you mind if I write my own CSS for it just to show you overall grid ? SOrry, but modifying your's take up more time. I can show you the layout

Answer (score 0):

You can use the style `clear:all` on a div, which means that it appears below the previous div(s). Or you can use the tag `<br clear="all">` which does basically the same.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to use the Grid the code would be

```css
.container2 {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    }

    .left {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .right {
        width: 50%;
        float: right;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .tab {

        border: black solid 1px;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .tab button {
        background-color: inherit;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 15px 50px;
        transition: 0.3s;
        font-size: 16px;
        
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;

    }
```

```html
<div class="container2">

        <div id="hp_slider_1" class="tabcontent">

            <div class="left">
                <div class="tabheading">
                    <p>Heading</p>
                </div>

                <div class="slidertab">
                    <h4 class="rightheading">Content1</h4>
                    <p class="righttext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                        incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                        ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
                        in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
                        cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="button_learnmore">Learn more.</a>
                </div>


            </div>


            <div class="right">
                <div class="tabheading">
                    <p>Heading</p>
                </div>

                <div class="texttab">
                    <h4 class="rightheading">Content1</h4>
                    <p class="righttext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                        incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                        ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
                        in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
                        cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="button_learnmore">Learn more.</a>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="hp_slider_2" class="tabcontent">
            <h3>Paris</h3>
            <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="hp_slider_3" class="tabcontent">
            <h3>Tokyo</h3>
            <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="hp_slider_4" class="tabcontent">
            <h3>fourth</h3>
            <p>Hello.</p>
        </div>





        <div class="tab">
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'hp_slider_1')">Button1 </button>

            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'hp_slider_2')">Button2</button>

            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'hp_slider_3')">Button3</button>

            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event,'hp_slider_4')">Button4</button>
        </div>



    </div>
```